# Infinite login loop on Facebook app using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I built an app based on one of the Facebook Developer sample apps, however a few days ago both my app and the Facebook sample app stopped working for all users - they now go into an infinite loop after you login: http://myfbse.com/socialmovies/

Here is the link to the sample code I have been using:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/18/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-pull-the-movies-friends-like/

I have tested on several computers, different browsers, tried to add and remove the apps from my Facebook account and cleared all cookies etc.

I'm wondering how I can find out what the problem is, a migration issue, a bug or something else? I already ran the app through the Facebook debugging tool and it didn't flag any problems. Is there another way to get more detailed information about what is causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information, is there any error or exception? Also, check that you do not have any careless copy-paste `'` or space in your appSecret.

Comment: I didn't get any error or exception message... after logging into the app the page just keeps refreshing which you can see yourself here: http://myfbse.com/socialmovies/

Comment: I'm also sure that it is not an error with the appSecret as it was working fine before and I didn't touch the code, it just stopped working.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem the other day, but it turned out I was receiving a cached status triggering the loop. You'll need to post code though so we can see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: You can see all the code on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/18/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-pull-the-movies-friends-like/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the infinite loop by replacing the auth code from the Facebook Developer sample app with the auth code here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

I guess the sample auth code is out of date.